# Unable to Connect to Hbase through Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am trying to connect to Hbase from Java. Hbase -Version 1.0.0
But I am unable to connect it. Kindly tell me what I am missing as I am new to Hbase.
Here is my code

```
public class HbaseAddRetrieveData{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        TableName tableName = TableName.valueOf("stock-prices");


    Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.master","LocalHost:60000");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "LocalHost");
    conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
    System.out.println("Config set");
    Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
    System.out.println("Connection");
    Admin admin = conn.getAdmin();
    if (!admin.tableExists(tableName)) {
        System.out.println("In admin");
        admin.createTable(new HTableDescriptor(tableName).addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("cf")));
    }

    Table table = conn.getTable(tableName);
    Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("AAPL10232015"));
    p.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("close"), Bytes.toBytes(119));
    table.put(p);

    Result r = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes("AAPL10232015")));
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

Below is the error I am facing :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:131)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:56)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:287)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:267)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:139)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:134)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:823)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:601)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:365)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:281)
at com.tcs.healthcare.HbaseRetrieveData.main(HbaseRetrieveData.java:32)
```

Kindly guide me through this

Comment: can you share your hbase-site.xml and /etc/hosts

Comment: Your Zookeeper seems bad, and hostnames are not correct

Answer (score 0):

change `L` in localhost to `l`  and 'H' to 'h'

```
Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    conf.set("hbase.master","localhost:60000");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
    conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost");
    conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
```

If you are using remote machine, then conf.set("hbase.master","remotehost:60000"); even its not working then you check all the jars (which are remote) in the classpath

if you are using maven you can point to the jars which are there in cluster.

you can go to cluster and check below command to know the version of jars which are there in remote machine.

```
`hbase classpath`
```

Same version jars should be there in your client machine. For ex hbasex.jar in the remote machine and you are using hbasey.jar then it wont connect.

Moreover, please check from client machine you can able to ping server/cluster or not. Generally there will be firewall restrictions.

Comment: and the H as well?

Comment: I am connecting to the remote server. My localhost here is: XX.XX.XX.XX

Comment: ya in that case it should be possible. But check the network  and other things. Generally if you are able to ping the remote host from client machine then it should be done with out any hassle.

Comment: check that all the client jars of  remote machine/cluster are in the class path of client machine

Comment: @RamPrasadG : Yes, the jars are present.

Comment: I am able to connect through putty and create tables. But unable to do through Code

Comment: Yes that's what I am telling you have to check any security policy or setting which is stopping you from connecting through windows. normally remote machines doesn't have access permissions in a secured environment.